# Can't decrypt https traffic with wireshark

Tags: linux, https, wireshark

I am trying to decrypt https traffic according to these guides:

https://linuxhint.com/decrypt-ssl-tls-wireshark/

https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/

But nothing is written to the `.ssl-log.key` file.
I have Linux Mint 20.3 x86_64 , installed browsers Brave , Firefox and LIbreWolf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, it turns out because I recently changed the shell from `bash` to `fish`, `firefox` did not see the environment variables I created. I changed the shell back to bash, followed all the instructions again and it worked!
And I launch `firefox` from terminal.